# How to include Square root sign as depicted in the following image in android?

Tags: android, square-root

I need to include the following square root sign in my android as a Text resource in Button control. Any guesses?

[image: Square Root Symbol]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy this and paste in your String resource file.

```
<string name="sqr_root">√¯¯</string>
```

Here is the Result:

[image: Square Root Symbol Result]

Comment: http://www.atm.ox.ac.uk/user/iwi/charmap.html
I always refer this site for any special characters came across during my projects.

Answer (score 7):

The unicode code for square root symbol is `221A`. You can define string resource as:

```
<string name="square_root_symbol">\u221a</string>
```

And then use it in your button:

```
<Button ... android:text="@string/square_root_symbol" />
```

---

[image]

Comment: Please see the image I included carefully. It also has horizontal line on top of square root sign. I already have above image placed in my button. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: If you don't like the unicode symbol, just make the icon and use it instead of text.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can have it like this,

```
√ - Alt+251
```

Also look at this link - [ASCII](http://www.livio.net/main/asciichar.asp)

Else you can use the image of square root and include inside a button using the property

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/square_root"
```

Comment: Please see the image I included carefully. It also has horizontal line on top of square root sign. I already have above image placed in my button. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Means its working in my iPhone app perfectly. But I dont know the same for android.

Comment: Well, you can copy that Image and keep on the Button for working in Android.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to put &#8730; into the string resource.

Comment: Please see the image I included carefully. It also has horizontal line on top of square root sign. I already have above image placed in my button. Thanks for the suggestion